# Fixing base_url in database, why?

Tags: magento-1.9, security

I have to maintain a **Magento** `1.9` *e-commerce* website.

I can see that URL is **hard coded** in **database**

- web/secure/base_url
- web/unsecure/base_url

Why this is recommanded ?

What could be unsecure to use `{{base_url}}` ?

Answer (score -1):

Each website in a Magento installation has a base URL that is assigned to the storefront and to the Admin. If you have a security certificate for your domain, you can configure either, or both base URLs to operate over a securely encrypted SSL channel. Unsecure base URLs begin with “http,” and secure base URLs begin with “https.”

> Unsecure Base URL: http://www.yourdomain.com/magento/
>
> Secure Base URL: https://www.yourdomain.com/magento/
>
> URL with IP address: http://10.9.220.154/magento/

If Magento was installed before you registered a domain, the base URL might include the IP address of the server. If you don’t yet have security certificate, the store will not be able to switch to secure URLs (https) for transactions that normally take place over the secure socket layer (SSL). These configuration settings can be updated later to reflect the values you need before the store “goes live.”

Source: Magento

Comment: in fact, my question was more, whats are _pros_/_cons_ between using a fixed (in **database**) _web/secure/base_url_ and using `{{base_url}}` (in **database**)